# Tracing loading of ELF file

Tags: linux, elf

Is it possible to trace loading of ELF executable from typing name of program and pressing enter until execution of main function? If yes, then how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
man ld.so
```

will tell you about LD_DEBUG.

Answer (score 2):

How about strace?

```
strace myprog myargs...
```

This will launch your program and print all the system calls as they are made, which I assume is what you meant by "trace."  You can just stop looking at the output once you see your own code being executed.

Comment: strace only traces system calls once the program begins executing. It doesn't debug the ELF loading process itself.

Comment: yea, I tried this, but I was thinking if it is possible to see execution of functions do_execve, search_binary_handler etc., which are executed before _start.

Comment: You are confounding things in the kernel with things in the process.

Comment: ld.so is inside the process and does the elf loading. Except for the tiny bit in the kernel, which you can't trace.